# How to add parameter that will never be used to expression tree in C#?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, expression-trees

I have a method in my code `MyMethod`: `public void MyMethod(String input)`. It is a method for `MyNamespace.MyClass`, and the instance of `MyClass` that I am using is `MyObject`.
I am creating an event handler that calls `MyObject.MyMethod` with the `input` parameter always set to `"test"`. However, I am creating it using an expression tree. Here is my current code, which manages to set `input`, but not the required `Object` and `EventArgs` parameters of an event handler:

```
Expression.Lambda(Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(MyObject), typeof(MyNamespace.MyClass).GetMethod("MyMethod"), Expression.Constant("test"), Expression.Parameter(typeof(Object), "sender"), Expression.Parameter(typeof(EventArgs), "e"))).Compile();
```

I get error: `Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Void MyMethod(System.String)'`.

When I try to define the last two `Expression.Parameter`s directly under `Expression.Lambda`, I get a `Parameter count mismatch` error.

The last working code I have simply takes out the last two `Expression.Parameter`s completely.

How can I define these parameters, even though I will not use them, to make the method into an event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misplaced closing parenthesis. `sender` and `e` are parameters of the Lambda and not of MyMethod, they should added as parameters in Expression.Lambda :

```cs
Expression.Lambda(
    Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(MyObject), typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("MyMethod"), Expression.Constant("test")), 
    Expression.Parameter(typeof(Object), "sender"), 
    Expression.Parameter(typeof(EventArgs), "e")
).Compile();
```

Notice the `Expression.Call` closing parenthesis is after `Expression.Constant("test")`

Comment: I had to add ``(Action<Object, EventArgs>)`` before the code, but this worked. Thank you!